# Removing non-alphabetic characters in VBScript run from command line

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm trying to remove all the non-alphabetic characters in a string in a VBScript that will run from the command line.

Here's what I have thus far:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim test
test = "Hello:, world!"
test = strClean(test)
WScript.Echo(test)

Function strClean(strVal)
  Set objRegEx     = CreateObject(“VBScript.RegExp”)
  objRegEx.Global  = True
  objRegEx.Pattern = “[^A-Za-z\n\r]”
  strSearchString  = objRegEx.Replace(strVal, “”)
End Function
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> my.vbs (8, 35) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Invalid character

Comment: That's not your actual code, because there are not enough lines to match the location the error message provides. If you want help figuring out why your code isn't working, post your code.

Comment: @KenWhite updated.

Comment: replace the Unicode quotes with ASCII

Comment: @Slai Please post your question as the answer, so I can mark it as such.

Comment: No need, I think the comment is noticeable enough. BTW, in VBScript you can use `Set objRegEx = New RegExp` instead of the late binding version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes you're using are Unicode and are invalid.
You should replace them by ASCII ones.

<sub>This is a community answer from Slai's comment that doesn't want to write an answer.
[See this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598) for more info.</sub>